# How to detect operating system with GIMP scheme?

Tags: operating-system, scheme, gimp, script-fu

I am using a few simple script-fus written in GIMP's scheme. (And that is the most I've used of scheme...)

I use them on machines running either Windows or Linux. Most times that is not a problem, but sometimes it is, namely when dealing with '\' vs. '/' on file paths.

**Is there a simple way to detect on which operating system GIMP is running, from a Scheme script-fu?** I haven't found anything on "[Revised^5 Report on the Algorithmic Language Scheme](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs.html)" (but I may have not looked in the correct place)

One *trick* I can do is to check for the existence of a given file, e.g., the following works just fine

```
(define (script-fu-operating-system)
  (let* ((the-os "windows"))
    (if (= 1 (car (file-glob "/usr/bin/gimp" 0)))
        (set! the-os "linux"))
    (gimp-message the-os)))
```

As suggested by Michael Schumacher, I tried using both '/' and '\'.

On Windows it worked as expected, e.g. for (file-jpeg-load), with ...

... backslashes (only needs to escape them):

```
(file-jpeg-load RUN-INTERACTIVE "C:\\Users\\my.user\\Pictures\\test.jpg" "")
```

... slashes:

```
(file-jpeg-load RUN-INTERACTIVE "C:/Users/my.user/Pictures/test.jpg" "")
```

... even works with mixed (back)slashes !!

```
(file-jpeg-load RUN-INTERACTIVE "C:/Users\\my.user/Pictures\\test.jpg" "")
```

Yet for (file-glob) it only works with the *proper* backslashes:

```
(file-glob "C:\\Users\\my.user\\Pictures\\*.jpg" 1) => OK (the file list)
(file-glob "C:/Users/my.user/Pictures/*.jpg" 1) => NOK (empty list)
```

Comment: / should work on Windows as well (even in Windows Explorer, although it changes those to \ after confirming a path). Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: Tricks like this are all you gonna get using scheme. (script-fu). If you intend to write full-fledged, multi-platform scripts, I  suggest you to write your GIMP scripts in Python instead. (Detecting the O.S. is a matter of e `import sys` and the OS. name is available in the variable `sys.platform` - but them, you don't need it since for file access the language automatically translates "/" to "\" as needed under Windows..
Moreover, you might appreciate the fact that to assign a variable you write `the_os = "whatever I want"` instead of a scoped `(let * (( the_os "value")) ... )`

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher Yes, / works on Windows. Sometimes... It does with (file-jpeg-load), but it does not with (file-glob). Thanks for pointing that out, I added it to my question, for future reference. Sorry for taking so long to follow up but I only have Windows at work and only today I could take a moment to test that

Comment: @jsbueno If your comment were a reply I'd accept it, as that is exactly what I was asking. I thank and take mental note on the suggestion about Python, but now is not the time to look at yet another language :-) Also, forgive the long delay

Comment: Thanks - the fact that file-glob is platform-specific here is most likely a bug. I don't recall a report about this - if you like, you could file one at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/page.cgi?id=browse.html&product=gimp

Comment: (promoted comment to answer as mentioned by O.P.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricks like what you describe  are all you gonna get using scheme (script-fu). If you intend to write full-fledged, multi-platform scripts, I suggest you to write your GIMP scripts in Python instead. (Detecting the O.S. is a matter of e import sys and the O.S. name is available in the variable sys.platform.
 - but them, you would not actually need the system for this spefic case,  since for file access the language automatically translates "/" to "\" as needed under Windows.

Moreover, scheme is generally harder to learn, write and maintain, besides having a standard library which is a fraction of the one used in a standard Python install.  The only cases I could recommend Script-fu instead of scheme are: if you are already proficient in scheme/lisp and not in Python at all, or, if you are just adapting/fixing an existing script.